# Discarding a Linux virtual drive

Tags: linux, bash, mount

From what I understand the process of creating a virtual drive in Linux goes like this

```
fallocate -l size /path/to/file.img;
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/tofile.img bs=1M count=N;
mkfs -t ext3 /path/to/file.img;
mkdir /path/to/mounted;
mount -t auto -o loop /path/to/file.img /math/to/mounted;
```

Once I am finished with the drive I issue

```
umount /path/to/mounted;
```

All well and good.  However, I have not yet quite understood how to deallocate the disk space allocated by the fallocate command.  I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me what to do.

Comment: This is a question for the Unix/Linux stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the `dd` call in your example since `fallocate` is doing the work. To *deallocate the disk space* simply remove the `.img` file as you would do with any other file:

```
rm /path/to/file.img
```

Comment: Yes, I had thought it might be and had removed the img that way.  However, I wanted to be sure that I was in fact the right way to do things. I thought the idea behind doing dd is to write 0 bytes to the virtual drive so it is less likely that it might be possible to read stale data at that location?

Comment: It depends on the use case whether you should initialize a file with zeros or not. In your case you don't need zeros since you are creating a file system on that file and that's why the initial file doesn't matter. Btw, if you would need to use `dd`, then using `fallocate` makes no sense anymore. Use either the one or the other